# Sorting wrapper for NSSet

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I need to fill a `UITableView` from an `NSSet` data source. Obviously I want the table sorted by some criteria.

I could simply create a sorted `NSArray` with `[mySet sortedArrayUsing...]` and use that for my table data source. But I need something more powerful: The underlying `NSSet` (`mySet`) changes over time, and I want the `UITableView` to update accordingly (still sorted, of course).

My best bet at the moment is to attach observers to the `NSSet` and refresh the `NSArray` and the `UITableView` every time the `NSSet` changes. It involves quite a bit of code however and is not too efficient.

So what I would like to have is something like this, I guess:

```
NSArray* sortedWrapperArray = [SortedWrapper wrapperFor:mySet sortUsing:sortCriteria];
```

where `sortedWrapperArray` automatically updates when the underlying set changes.

Is there something like this or similiar in the Objective-C/Cocoa world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app will run only on iOS 5.0 or newer, you can use `NSOrderedSet`

Comment: This is a good approach because `NSOrderedSet` provides a method called `-array` which returns a proxy array that is constantly updated as the backing ordered set is mutated.

Comment: This in combination with the -array method is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The question asks for sorted, not ordered (which is ordered by insertion order)

Answer (score 3):

If your underlying collection is `NSSet`, you will be forced to sort it from scratch every time the set changes, spending `O(N*Log(N))` time doing it. I think a much more efficient way of dealing with the issue is to replace `NSSet` with `NSMutableArray`, and keep it sorted through the insertions. Adding and removing elements in a sorted array would still be `O(N)`: although you can find the position using binary search (see `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` method), the insertion/removal is generally `O(N)` (with a very low constant, though). Maintaining uniqueness property of the set is also easy: if the binary search finds the same element that you were about to insert, simply skip the insertion. Same-value checks would take `O(Log(N))`

Comment: You state adding and removing elements in a sorted array would be `O(log n)` are you certain of that? Is `-[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]` truly  `O(1)`?

Comment: @Ief2 You are absolutely right - the cost will be dominated by the need to shift the data up or down the array. I fixed the answer, thank you very much!

Comment: dasblinkenlight I cannot really change the NSSet to NSMutableArray because I get the NSSet from an underlying component with a fixed interface. So I guess I need some kind of efficient wrapper around the NSSet.

Comment: Still I like your idea as I can incorporate it into my solution where I attach observers to the NSSet. The observers will then update a NSMutableArray using your method.